# Uniqueness of solutions - Picard Theorem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the IVP:
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            y'(x)=\sqrt[3]y & \quad  \\
            y(0)=0 & \quad
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
By Peano's Theorem, we know a solution exists in a rectangle. You can also solve this EDO getting $y(x)=\dfrac{2x}{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}$.
Since it isn't Lipschitz-Continuous, we can't use Picard's Theorem to ensure uniqueness.
I can't find find two solutions to show it isn't unique, any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$y(x)=0$$ also satisfies your initial value problem.

$$\begin{equation*}
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            y'(x)=\sqrt[3]y & \quad  \\
            y(0)=0 & \quad
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}$$

Comment: That was trivial! I could manage to get an $y(x)$ but your example works perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation $y'(x)=\sqrt[3]y$ is translation invariant, therefore, in addition to the zero function, all functions $y(x)=\frac 23 (x-a)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ with $a\ge 0$ are solutions of the initial value problem.